# Read battery consumption in linux

Tags: linux, bash, battery

I would like to monitor my system current Watt usage. The tricky part is that I have 2 batteries (BAT0 and BAT1).

I know that I can read the current power of BAT1 from this file: `sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/power_now`, BAT0 is basically the same.

#### Problem 1

The output of this file is: `4997000` which is probably micro watts.
I would like to format so the script displays a readable format.

#### Problem 2

As I have mentioned I have two batteries, so I have to determine which battery is currently used (so the mentioned file is not zero).

I would like to know how to display these with a preferably bash script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Final and working solution is this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Get the current battery levels
bat1=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity)
bat2=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/capacity)

# Calculate the average battery level
average=$(( ($bat1 + $bat2) / 2 ))

# Get the charging status of each battery
status1=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status)
status2=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status)

# Check if any of the batteries is charging
charging=false
if [ "$status1" == "Charging" ] || [ "$status2" == "Charging" ]; then
  charging=true
fi

# Battery current watt usage
if [ $(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/power_now)  == 0 ]; then
 bat_watt=$"$(echo "scale=2; $(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now)/1000000" | bc)W"
# bat_watt=$(awk '{print $1*10^-6 "W"}' /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now)
else
    bat_watt=$"$(echo "scale=2; $(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/power_now)/1000000" | bc)W"
    #bat_watt=$(awk '{print $1*10^-6.0f "W"}' /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/power_now)
fi

# Get the AC adapter status
ac_status=$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/AC/online)

# Output the battery levels, charging status, and AC adapter status

## Charging and AC is connected -> Green display
if [ "$charging" == true ] && [ "$ac_status" == 1 ]; then
  echo "%{F#00ff00}↑%{F-}%{F#00ff00}%{F-}  $average% $bat_watt AC" 

## Not charging and AC is connected (so batteries at threshold) -> White display
elif [ "$charging" == false ] && [ "$ac_status" == 1 ]; then
  echo "%{F#FFFFFF}%{F-} $average% AC"  

## Average battery are under 20% -> Red display
elif [ "$average" -lt 21 ]; then
  echo "%{F#FF0000}%{F-} $average% $bat_watt"  

## Else discharging
else
  echo "%{F#FFAA00}%{F-} $average% $bat_watt" 
fi

#elif [ "$charging" == true ] && [ "$ac_status" == 0 ]; then
#  echo "Average battery level: $average%, charging, AC unplugged"
```

For displaying I use a rofi script.
Everything i use is on this [page](https://github.com/Lolis4TheWin/polybar-thinkpad-battery).

Comment: [formatting code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: You are comparing the literal string `awk '{print $1*10^-6}' /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/power_now` to `0` which of course will never be true. You were probably looking for `$(awk ...)` but running the same command twice is also quite inelegant. This could probably be refactored to something like `awk '$1 > 0 {print $1*10^-6 ] { exit 1-($1==0)}' /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/power_now || awk '{print $1*10^-6}' /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now`

Comment: It is working, but it has a big problem: `awk: cmd. line:1: $1 > 0 {print $1*10^-6 exit 1-($1==0)}
awk: cmd. line:1:                        ^ syntax error
4.666`